# onclick function doesn't work in an Ajax loaded button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So, I have a website which after selecting day loads some forms with Ajax request. In this loaded website (I just add its content to a modal), I have a button

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add">
   Dodaj kolejny przedział.
</button>
```

Which should call the function addInput(), which is defined in the "master" html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

fields = 0;
function addInput() {
  alert("dodajemy");
   if (fields != 24) {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "test<br>";
  // document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "Poczatek: <input type='text' value='' />Koniec: <input type='text' value='' /><br />";
  fields += 1;
} else {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "No wiecej ci nie potrzeba<br>";
}

};  

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, type: 'POST',
headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" } });

$("#wybierz_pokoj").submit(function() {

    var url = "/testowa/wybierz_pokoj" // the script where you handle the form input.
    document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML = "Czekamy"
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           evalJS: true,
           data: $("#wybierz_pokoj").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           cache: false,
           success: function(data)
           {
              document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML = data;
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
}); 
</script>
```

And after clicking the button, I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: addInput is not defined" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't use inline javascript (`onclick="addInput()"`). You're already using jQuery, use it better. Also getElementById? `document.getElementById('text')` == `$('#text')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the function inside the document.ready call - try defining it outside like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addInput() {
  alert("dodajemy");
   if (fields != 24) {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "test<br>";
  // document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "Poczatek: <input type='text' value='' />Koniec: <input type='text' value='' /><br />";
  fields += 1;
} else {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "No wiecej ci nie potrzeba<br>";
}

};  


$(document).ready(function() {

fields = 0;

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, type: 'POST', headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" } });
$("#wybierz_pokoj").submit(function() {
    var url = "/testowa/wybierz_pokoj"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML = "Czekamy";
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           evalJS: true,
           data: $("#wybierz_pokoj").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           cache: false,
           success: function(data)
           {
              document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML = data;
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
}); 
</script>
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with the "fields" variable, but if you need it ay any point, make sure it's also declared outside the document.ready function as well.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is not to write inline JS and use jQuery the way it was intended to be used.

Remove the onclick from your HTML and bind the event with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('button[name="add"]').on('click', function(){
        addInput();
    });

    fields = 0;
    function addInput() { // etc etc
```

You don't really need the function within the scope of that dom.ready either.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qz526/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is scope. The `addInput` function is inside the the `document.ready()` anonymous function, so it's not visible outside that scope. Javascript in `onXXX` attributes is executed in the global scope, so it can't access `addInput`.

The simplest solution is to move the definition of `addInput` outside the anonymous function, or change it to:

```
window.addInput = function() {
    ...
};
```

Or instead of using inline Javascript, you could use event delegation. See [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)